# Replace one row with mupltiple rows form a different table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables:
Table 1:

```
Number| Code | Value
-------+------+-----
Garden |A0,C2 | 100
Garden |rest  | 500
House  |A0,C2 | 100
House  |rest  | 500
```

Table2:

```
|Code|
+-----+
|A0  |
|B1  |
|C2  |
|D3  |
|E4  |
```

I would like to get a Table that looks something like this:

```
Number| Code | Value
-------+------+-----
Garden |A0    | 100
Garden |B1    | 500
Garden |C2    | 100
Garden |D3    | 500
Garden |E4    | 500
House  |A0    | 100
House  |B1    | 500
House  |C2    | 100
House  |D3    | 500
House  |E4    | 500
```

Does anyone know a SQL Statement on how I can get to this table

Changing either table 1 or table 2 is not possible

Comment: Don't store data as comma separated items, it will only cause you lots of trouble!

Comment: @jarlh unfortunately I do not have controll over it

Comment: SQL Server version?

Answer (score 1):

You should fix the `table1` so it is not using lists represented as comma-delimited strings.  You should have a separate table for this.  There are many good reasons for this.

Assuming that you are stuck with someone-else's really, really bad data model, you can use a `join`.  There are several approaches. SQL Server 2017+ has built-in `string_split()` function.

Then, you want to generate the rows with a `cross join` and bring in the values you want using `left join`s:

```
select n.number, t2.code, coalesce(t1.value, t1rest.value) as value
from (select distinct number from table1) n cross join
     table2 t2 left join
     table1 t1 
     on t1.number = n.number and ',' + t1.codes + ',' like '%,' + t2.code + ',%' left join
     table1 t1rest
     on t1rest.number = n.number and t1rest.codes = 'rest';
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=342f5976e618d668859830406603dc60) is a db<>fiddle

Comment: @clem995 . . . Ah, I see.  I didn't understand the problem.  I've updated the answer and provided a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a fan of this solution, as the `JOIN` with an `EXISTS` is ugly. I strongly suggest fixing your data model here. You shouldn't be using delimited data in your table, and you shouldn't be using a value like `'rest'` to denote you want all other values other than those previously defined. The result set you get here is a normalised dataset, and that is exactly how you should be storing your data:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (Number varchar(6), --A number is a varchar?
                     Code varchar(50),
                     [Value] int);

INSERT INTO dbo.Table1 (Number,
                        Code,
                        [Value])
VALUES ('Garden','A0,C2',100),
       ('Garden','rest',500),
       ('House','A0,C2',100),
       ('House','rest',500);

CREATE TABLE Table2 (Code char(2));
INSERT INTO dbo.Table2 (Code)
VALUES ('A0'),
       ('B1'),
       ('C2'),
       ('D3'),
       ('E4');

GO
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT T1.Number,
           SS.[value] AS Code,
           T1.[Value]
    FROM dbo.Table1 T1
         CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(T1.Code, ',')  SS)
SELECT C.Number,
       T2.Code,
       C.[Value]
FROM CTE C
     JOIN dbo.Table2 T2 ON C.Code = T2.Code
                        OR (C.Code = 'rest'
                       AND  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                                        FROM CTE e
                                        WHERE e.Number = C.Number
                                          AND e.Code = T2.Code))

GO

DROP TABLE dbo.Table1;
DROP TABLE dbo.Table2;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a45519fe9baabe92e709a64a6f989309)

If you aren't using SQL Server 2016+, you won't be able to use `STRING_SPLIT`. As a result I suggest looking up an "XML Splitter" or `delimitedsplit8k(_lead)`.

Comment: I somehow can not use "use Sandbox"

Comment: That's a hangover from my copy and pasting, @clem995 (you don't expect me to test scripts for SO in my production database/Instance do you? :) ). You do know what a `USE` statement does though, right?